# IOS - How to resolve this error -MPMusicPlayerController ErrorDomain.6 "Failed to prepare to play

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple-musickit

I integrate apple music API and get songID from API response and pass into MPMusicPlayerController in setQueue method.

Here is Code:

```
API: https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/search?term=pablo-honey

Response: 
{
    "results": {
        "songs": {
            "href": "/v1/catalog/us/search?limit=5&term=pablo-honey&types=songs",
            "next": "/v1/catalog/us/search?offset=5&term=pablo-honey&types=songs",
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": "35903761",
                    "type": "songs",
                    "href": "/v1/catalog/us/songs/35903761",
                    "attributes": {
                        "albumName": "The Jerky Boys 2",
                        "genreNames": [
                            "Comedy",
                            "Music"
                        ],
                        "trackNumber": 1,
                        "releaseDate": "1994-01-01",
                        "durationInMillis": 41933,
                        "isrc": "US39N0400253",
                        "artwork": {
                            "width": 1425,
                            "height": 1425,
                            "url": "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/y2004/m12/d07/h21/s06.cfbpldlx.jpg/{w}x{h}bb.jpg",
                            "bgColor": "0d091a",
                            "textColor1": "fdf2f8",
                            "textColor2": "f3e7da",
                            "textColor3": "cdc3cb",
                            "textColor4": "c5bab3"
                        },
                        "url": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/pablo-honey/35903759?i=35903761",
                        "playParams": {
                            "id": "35903761",
                            "kind": "song"
                        },
                        "discNumber": 1,
                        "hasCredits": false,
                        "isAppleDigitalMaster": false,
                        "hasLyrics": false,
                        "name": "Pablo Honey",
                        "previews": [
                            {
                                "url": "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/AudioPreview125/v4/e8/ed/7b/e8ed7bc0-4111-d3a6-e5b3-3929138e682d/mzaf_11433510887326099537.plus.aac.p.m4a"
                            }
                        ],
                        "artistName": "The Jerky Boys"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "1097862228",
                    "type": "songs",
                    "href": "/v1/catalog/us/songs/1097862228",
                    "attributes": {
                        "albumName": "Pablo Honey",
                        "genreNames": [
                            "Alternative",
                            "Music"
                        ],
                        "trackNumber": 1,
                        "releaseDate": "1993-02-22",
                        "durationInMillis": 208667,
                        "isrc": "GBAYE9200113",
                        "artwork": {
                            "width": 4000,
                            "height": 4000,
                            "url": "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music126/v4/0a/30/e8/0a30e802-d9a3-ba01-243c-774f7cd966fd/634904077969.png/{w}x{h}bb.jpg",
                            "bgColor": "ffffff",
                            "textColor1": "040a04",
                            "textColor2": "541407",
                            "textColor3": "363b36",
                            "textColor4": "764338"
                        },
                        "composerName": "Colin Greenwood, Ed O'Brien, Jonny Greenwood, Phil Selway & Thom Yorke",
                        "playParams": {
                            "id": "1097862228",
                            "kind": "song"
                        },
                        "url": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/you/1097862062?i=1097862228",
                        "discNumber": 1,
                        "hasCredits": false,
                        "isAppleDigitalMaster": false,
                        "hasLyrics": true,
                        "name": "You",
                        "previews": [
                            {
                                "url": "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/AudioPreview125/v4/43/0d/18/430d185f-5f4e-b4a3-04d1-05d4c2130dc8/mzaf_2514685066057802275.plus.aac.p.m4a"
                            }
                        ],
                        "artistName": "Radiohead"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "1097862419",
                    "type": "songs",
                    "href": "/v1/catalog/us/songs/1097862419",
                    "attributes": {
                        "albumName": "Pablo Honey",
                        "genreNames": [
                            "Alternative",
                            "Music"
                        ],
                        "trackNumber": 5,
                        "durationInMillis": 161533,
                        "releaseDate": "1993-02-22",
                        "isrc": "GBAYE9200114",
                        "artwork": {
                            "width": 4000,
                            "height": 4000,
                            "url": "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music126/v4/0a/30/e8/0a30e802-d9a3-ba01-243c-774f7cd966fd/634904077969.png/{w}x{h}bb.jpg",
                            "bgColor": "ffffff",
                            "textColor1": "040a04",
                            "textColor2": "541407",
                            "textColor3": "363b36",
                            "textColor4": "764338"
                        },
                        "composerName": "Colin Greenwood, Ed O'Brien, Jonny Greenwood, Phil Selway & Thom Yorke",
                        "playParams": {
                            "id": "1097862419",
                            "kind": "song"
                        },
                        "url": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/thinking-about-you/1097862062?i=1097862419",
                        "discNumber": 1,
                        "hasCredits": false,
                        "hasLyrics": true,
                        "isAppleDigitalMaster": false,
                        "name": "Thinking About You",
                        "previews": [
                            {
                                "url": "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/AudioPreview125/v4/67/77/7e/67777e27-7dd3-6e9a-6b76-d8e8f717f8f0/mzaf_10939723814371564312.plus.aac.p.m4a"
                            }
                        ],
                        "artistName": "Radiohead"
                    }
                }
```

Pass ID value in MPMusicController but getting not prepare to play error.

Here is code of MPMusicController

```
private func getParametersFrom(ids: [String]) -> [MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters] {
        var parameters = [MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters]()
        for id in ids {
            if let parameter = MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters(dictionary: ["id": id, "kind": "song"]) {
                parameters.append(parameter)
            } else {
                print("PlayerQueue - Could not create play parameters from catalog id \(id)")
            }
        }
        return parameters
    }
```

Calling this function

```
  let parameters = getParametersFrom(ids: ids)
 player.setQueue(with: MPMusicPlayerPlayParametersQueueDescriptor(playParametersQueue: parameters))
```

So,Please help me about this issue.

Any help should be appreciated.
Thank you.